# Install Calligraplan in 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, calligra

Simple Question: How do i install calligraplan in Kubuntu 18.04 manually, since it isn't anymore available via apt-get?

Comment: @user535733 I'm not seeing it https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=calligraplan

Comment: Well, sure enough, it's in every release of Ubuntu *except* 18.04 (source:madison). Good catch. Also see bug [LP:#1758117](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calligra/+bug/1758117), Prior comment cheerfully withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but it seems 18.04 has no calligraplan package:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=calligraplan&searchon=names

This package is however included in earlier and newer ubuntu releases.

I found some service with kplato package, it should be the same application probably:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/trinity-r14-amd64/kplato-trinity_14.0.5-0ubuntu18.04.0+0_amd64.deb.html

Comment: Is there a way to install the package for 18.10?